# laravel5.2 errors not show up in blade

Tags: laravel

I am trying solve this wired problem for hours, but still the errors message won't show up in template.
I have make sure the web middleware (which contains StartSession and ShareErrorsFromSession) is wrapped all my route.

```
Route::group(['namespace'=>'admin','prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>['web']],function (){
Route::get('index','AdminController@index');
Route::get('addCase','CaseController@create');
Route::any('upload','AdminController@upload');
Route::resource('case', 'CaseController');
```

});

```
    public function store(Request $resquest)
{
    //
    $validator = Validator::make($resquest->all(), [
        'title' => 'required',
    ]);
    if($validator->passes()){

    }else{
        return back()->withErrors($validator);
    }

}


   <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="{{action('admin\CaseController@store')}}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            @if (count($errors) > 0)
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            @endif
                <button>submit</button>
        </form>
```

please help!

the validation is worked, but the errors vanished

Comment: post your code instead of image

Comment: ok , I have post  code on

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

In controller

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'title' => 'required'});
  if($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);
  }
```

In view page

```
   @if ($errors->any())
        <ul class="alert alert-danger">
          @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endif
```